# How do I use lineSortKey in Mapbox iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I can't find any examples of how to use [lineSortKey](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/api/11.0.0-beta.5/Structs/LineLayer.html#/s:10MapboxMaps9LineLayerV11lineSortKeyAA5ValueOySdGSgvp), and testing with constants seems to indicate it's not working the way I assume. Where can I find more info on how to use this? Or can someone present an example?

And how does this interact with `LayerPosition`?

Answer (score 0):

According to Ivan from the MapboxDevs discord:

`lineSortKey` allows to sort line features rendered by one layer. For example, you have 3 lines rendered by a `LineLayer`, every line is represented by a GeoJSON Feature with some property (`sortKey`). You make an expression that retrieves this value and assigns it to the layer.